# Show/hide div upon option select with preselected div shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to show hidden div depending on the selected option, with the div of the preselected option already shown.

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
 <option value="apple" data-fruit-name="apple" selected="selected">Apple</option>
 <option value="mango" data-fruit-name="mango">Mango</option>
</select>

<div class="message" data-fruit-name="apple">I'm Apple.</div>
<div class="message" data-fruit-name="mango">I'm Mango.</div>
```

The message, if not selected, should be hidden. But since Apple is preselected, I would like its message to be preshown as well. When the user selects Mango, Apple's message should be hidden, Mango's message should be shown, and vice versa.

Comment: Yea so wheres the relevant code? This is just HTML, did you tried doing it yourself first?

Comment: There you go.. http://jsfiddle.net/h8BHy/

Comment: why do you want to hide or show div?You just want to display message of selected option.Don't complicate with to show or hide of div.Just refer this link http://api.jquery.com/change/ --this is simple jquery change function.

Comment: @Mr.Alien you mean the jquery? Tried it, not working. Its pretty easy for others.

Comment: @chinnu i have my own reasons which i dont have to tell you, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#fruits').change(function() {
    var fruitName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('fruit-name');
    $('.message[data-fruit-name="' + fruitName + '"]').show().siblings('.message').hide();
}).change();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5qU4/)**

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
$('#fruits').change(function (){
  $('.message').hide();
  var fruit = $(this).find('option:selected').data('fruit-name');
  $('.message[data-fruit-name="' + fruit + '"]').show();
});
```

But it would be better to refactor message elements to be identified for example like this:

```
<div class="message" id="apple">I'm Apple.</div>
<div class="message" id="mango">I'm Mango.</div>
```

and then change code to this:

```
$('#fruits').change(function (){
  $('.message').hide();
  var fruit = $(this).find('option:selected').data('fruit-name');
  $('#' + fruit).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the val() to select the proper div and show it and use .siblings to hide the others:

#### JS:

```
$(function(){

    //Hide initially
    $("#"+$("select").val()).siblings("div").hide();

    $("select").change(function(){
   
        //Hide/show onChange
        $("#"+$("select").val()).show().siblings("div").hide();
    
    });

});
```

#### HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="a" selected>a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avQLP/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#fruits').change(function(){
        var display = $(this).val();
        $('.message[data-fruit-name='+display+']').show().siblings('.message').hide();
    });
});

<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
 <option value="apple" data-fruit-name="apple" selected="selected">Apple</option>
 <option value="mango" data-fruit-name="mango">Mango</option>
</select>

<div class="message" data-fruit-name="apple" style='display:none;'>I'm Apple.</div>
<div class="message" data-fruit-name="mango" style='display:none;'>I'm Mango.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".message").hide();

$("#fruits").change(function() { 
     var _this = $(this);
    $(".message").each(function() { 
        if(_this.find("option:selected").data("fruit-name") == $(this).data("fruit-name")) {
         $(".message").hide();
         $(this).show();   
        }
    }); 

}).change();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5uw8/)